# Insert word in char at specific position in SQL

Tags: sql, insert, char

I'd like to insert in SQL a new word in a column with text after another specific word, for example: I have the text "My car is black" and I'd like to insert the word new after My, the new text should be: My new car is black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention the database, so I'll answer for SQL Server.  It happens to have a function called `stuff()` that really helps in this case.  The following is the code:

```
with t as (select 'My car is black' as col)
select STUFF(col, charindex('My', col) + LEN('My') + 1, 0, 'new ')
from t;
```

You can do the equivalent in other databases, by extracting pieces of the string.  However, string functions tend to vary among databases so there is no form that works in all (or even almost all) databases.

EDIT:

Based on your description, I think the following is perhaps what you really want:

```
select replace(col, 'sticker', 'sticker SHOCK')
from t;
```

This will work in most databases.  You can do this as an update as well:

```
update t
    set col = replace(col, 'sticker', 'sticker SHOCK')
    where col like '%sticker%';
```

Comment: +1 didn't even think of using `STUFF`. However, I have a feeling this question is probably for MySQL.

Comment: Hi, Actually I'd like to modify in opencart (in phpmyadmin - sql) the product name, which varies, I have a table 'product_description' with a column 'name'. Each name start with "sticker" and after this word I'd like to add another one. Also there would be a condition for that, if another column named 'custom_title' would contain a phrase. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to concatenate the left and right part of the phrase to new word you want to insert. Depending on the DBMS, you would use various functions to determine the left and right parts.

In SQL Server, you could do:

```
UPDATE tbl SET phrase = LEFT(phrase, 3) + 'new ' + RIGHT(phrase, 12);
```

Which would produce

```
|              PHRASE |
-----------------------
| My new car is black |
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2a65c/1)